# How do I stop Adobe Bridge CS6 consuming so much memory?

Tags: adobe-bridge

In Process Explorer, Bridge.exe's private bytes are way over my RAM (16 GB used, while my system only has 12 GB RAM).

It might just be a particularly thorough indexing phase (I've tried clearing cache), but it always crashes my system eventually.

I'm running Win7 64-bit. I may have Photoshop (CS6 also) open at the same time, but it doesn't seem to matter either way. I have looked through everything I can find in the menus.

How do I stop Bridge from consuming all of my RAM?

Comment: What do you mean by "indexing phase"? What OS version are you using? 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: @gronostaj Bridge indexes media information for later retrieval (probably photo and video thumbnails, metadata etc.)

Comment: @Chandra42 Cataloger which consumes 12GB of RAM? Unique services it provides? +1

Comment: @SSTR Adobe Bridge basically opens all your image/video files and creates a thumbnail of them, which is stored as another (smaller) image in a central cache folder (unless a project-local folder is specified).  I've tried purging this cache and moving from central to local cache stores -all on my PC, but having one cache-per folder vs. one centralised cache.